# Preventing hackers from ruining my MediaWiki site

Tags: mediawiki, hacked

I am running on Bitnami and AWS. Hackers have removed all the content on my MediaWiki and posted advertisements and junk.

Is there a way to roll back to my previous site version and stop unauthorized edits?

Comment: disable comments and user registration.  Create the accounts yourself.

Comment: As for reversing the changes, restore from a backup, that is one of your only options.

Comment: Doesn't MediaWiki have… edit history?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about administering self-hosted software.

Comment: [webmasters.se] or [security.se] might be better places. Read the Help Center before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is:

- Check your backups.
- Subscribe to the [MediaWiki mailinglist](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-l) (in order to be informed of security issues and other updates).
- Install a new clean MediaWiki
- Configure the user account to be created by you.
- Restore the actual data from a backup (preferable from before the first spam links).
- Only now make the wiki publically accesable.